# SQLite database partitioning

Tags: database, sqlite, database-partitioning

I want to create sqlite partition structure,
I created 3 databases,
I attached those 3 databases to another database which will be parent with

```
ATTACH DATABASE '1.db' as 1
ATTACH DATABASE '2.db' as 2
ATTACH DATABASE '3.db' as 3
```

after i `.quit` the parent database the database attachments detach, How can I keep them attached even if I quit the database?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attachments are never permanent.

Every program that opens the database needs to make any attachments it needs.

If you really think you need partitioning, using another database [might be a better idea](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

Comment: CL: that page actually gives a suggestion on how to partition sqlite... so it's quite an appropriate use!

Answer (score 5):

Attachments are not permanent.

When partitioning a SQLITE database, the natural way to do it is to create a separate database for each X, where X is some element in the system that represents a query boundary that you don't need to cross.

For example, you can create a separate database for each user.

Or you can hash to 2 bytes on some key, and create a database for each pair of bytes, ameliorating lock contention.

If you don't have a natural partition in your data, and you need to scale beyond the capabilities of sqlite, you should consider another DB.